# How to make randomize redo until get the number I want?

Tags: system-verilog

A basic sequence class for randomize reset below:

```
class random_reset;
   rand int rst_period;

   constraint  rst_range { rst_period inside {[1:100]}; }

   task random_system_reset (
                 ref reg rst,
                 ref reg clk);
      begin
     rst = 1;
     repeat (rst_period) @(posedge clk);
     rst = 0;
      end
   endtask

endclass
```

However, I test need at least 6 clocks. Got anyway to make sure when I call this class, will get the random value bigger than 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep your original constraint as-is, but in some circumstances, you need to enforce the period to be 6 or more, you can use `randomize() with`:

```
random_reset rr = new();

initial rr.randomize() with { rst_period >= 6; };
```

For this `rr` object, `rst_period` will be between 6 and 100.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 18.7 *In-line constraints—randomize() with*.